# Can I modify Linux keyboard combos to perform certain tasks?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a lot of files in my folders and for a particular task, I have to go through with each one, right click, click properties and then note down certain information. Instead of having to add these few mouse clicks, would it be possible to assign e.g. ctrl+alt+p or whatever to bring up the properties dialog for the selected file?

If this was possible, it would eliminate the need for me to use the mouse at all.

I was curious if anyone had any thoughts on this.

I'm using Ubuntu 20. Thanks!

Comment: can we know the "certain information" and have one example? There should be command line tools to get such informaiton easily.

Comment: I'd like to note down size, dates, and change permissions. But, doing this through terminal is not the way I'd like to. I understand it may be easier for some, but I'd prefer to do it through the GUI, hence the question above, if possible. With all respect.

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough you did not say so explicitly I assume you are using Nautilus as your file manager. In the burger menu (top right) you can open settings for "keyboard shortcuts". There you can see what hotkeys are set. In my case the combination "Alt+Enter" opens the property window of the selected file entry.
<strike>If you want, what you are doing seems like something, that could be automated with a script. If you say what info you are copying, and how you want to store the info in a file, someone here could offer you a script to do this hands off.</strike> You want to do it in gui.